# Remove item in listview on Tap

Tags: listview, xamarin, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged, inotifycollectionchanged

This is my code:

```
public partial class MyGS: ContentPage {
  public MyGS() {
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new MyGSViewModel();
  }


public class MyGSViewModel: INotifyCollectionChanged {
  public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

  public ObservableCollection < SchItem > Items {get;private set;}

  public MyGSViewModel() {
   Items = new ObservableCollection<SchItem>();
   //Item Population 

  public void removeItem(int rid, int lid) {
     SchItem myItem = Items[lid];
     Items.Remove(myItem);
     CollectionChanged ? .Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, myItem));
  }
}

public class SchItem {
  public int realm_id {get;set;}
  public int list_id {get;set;}

  public ICommand TapCommand {
   get {return new Command(() => {
     Debug.WriteLine("COMMAND: " + list_id);
     MyGSViewModel gsvm = new MyGSViewModel();
     gsvm.removeItem(realm_id, list_id);
      });
   }
  }
 }
}
```

When removeItem method is called the view doesn't refresh and the item will be no deleted from ListView, maybe the problem is about the CollectionChanged but i don't get how to fix that.

> Note: Debugging in Android Device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things. Usually `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged` is used instead of `INotifyCollectionChanged`. If you switch to that and also implement a more common binding pattern, your ViewModel would look like this:

```
public class MyGSViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection < SchItem > Items {
        get { return _items; }
        private set {
            if(_items != value) {
                _items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(); //Execute the event anytime an object is removed or added
            }
        }
    }

    public MyGSViewModel() {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<SchItem>();
        //Item Population
    }

    public void removeItem(int rid, int lid) {
        SchItem myItem = Items[lid];
        Items.Remove(myItem); //If an object is removed, the OnPropertyChanged() method will be run from 'Items's setter
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I would also suggest moving the `OnPropertyChanged` method and the `PropertyChanged` event into a base ViewModel so that all of your ViewModels can inherit from the base and you do not have duplicate that code everywhere.

*Edit: Just noticed that you have your `TapCommand` defined within your `SchItem` class. In there you are newing up a new `MyGSViewModel` instance everytime that command is run. So unless everything in your `MyGSViewModel` is set to static (which I do not recommend), that is not ever going to effect your `MyGS` page. In addition to what I suggested above, I would suggest using the `Tapped` event instead of a `Command` since you need to pass multiple parameters into your `removeItem` method.

To do that...

In your XAML:

```
<Button Tapped="OnItemTapped"/>
```

-OR-

```
<Label>
  <Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnItemTapped"/>
  </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

In your `MyGS` `ContentPage`:

```
public partial class MyGS : ContentPage {

    private MyGSViewModel _viewModel;

    public MyGS() {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _viewModel = new MyGSViewModel();
    }

    private void OnItemTapped(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SchItem item = (SchItem)((Image)sender).BindingContext;

        if(item == null) { return; }

        _viewModel.removeItem(item.realm_id, item.list_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: About the edit, i got `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. ` maybe because i have the tap command in Item definition class ?
Edit: I got SchItem back and not MyGSViewModel as CommandParameter

Comment: @Segamoto O right, because the `BindingContext` is the object since it is in a `ListView`... so in that case I would definitely recommend using the `Tapped` event. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Segamoto Check now

Comment: I get `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.` in ` SchItem item = (SchItem)sender;`

Comment: @Segamoto Then I will need to see the rest of your XAML. You are using a `ListView` binded to your `Items` collection via `ListView.ItemSource` right? If so, what does your `ItemTemplate` look like?

Comment: @Segamoto Damn, sorry about that. Really messing up today! Check out the `OnItemTapped` method now. The `sender` is actually the `Image` that your `TapGestureRecognizer` is attached to, so you need the `Image.BindingContext`